# Does casting double to int returns the round down number?

Tags: c, casting, double, math.h

I have the folowing example :

```
double x = 2.5;
int n = (int)x;
int k = (int) floor(x);
```

Does casting double to int returns the round down number? or I should use floor function?

Comment: it´ll return *truncated* value: `2.5 -> 2`; `2.99 -> 2` (fractional part removed)

Comment: Related: [Why does a float when converted to an int be rounded off below in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35008621/3049655)

Comment: "should use floor function?" --> consider using the `(int) round(x)` to round to nearest.

Answer (score 16):

Be careful with negative numbers. Casting will truncate towards 0. `floor` will truncate towards negative infinite.

If the value is positive, then both methods return the same truncated value.

Comment: Right. I totally forgot about negative rounding rules and what rounding up or down means there.

Answer (score 7):

Well `(int)` truncates the initial `double` value (fractional part removed)

```
  2.1  -> 2
  2.5  -> 2
  2.99 -> 2
```

it looks like `floor`, but they're not the same in case of *negative numbers*:

```
  (int)-2.1   -> -2
  floor(-2.1) -> -3.0
```

since `floor` returns max integer value that less or equal to the given argument

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the limitation of int and double.

```
int main(void)
{
    double val1 = INT_MAX + 10.5;
    int    val2 = val1;

    printf("val1 = %f\nval2 = %d\n", val1, val2);

    return (0);
}
```

This produce the output below :

```
val1 = 2147483657.500000
val2 = -2147483648
```

(I don't know if INT_MAX is standard, sorry).

Comment: casting an out of range double to int is undefined behavior

Comment: I didn't know, that's one more reason to be careful when casting.

Comment: INT_MAX is standard. Please add information about undefined behavior into the answer and also answer the actual question.